# How do I revert back to my original python installation from Enthought Canopy on Mint Linux 14 64-bit?

Tags: linux, bash, enthought

I am attempting to uninstall Enthought Canopy (Linux 64-bit installation) from my Mint Linux KDE machine. The Enthought help file says to remove the ~/Canopy directory.

How do I remove the Canopy directory from my $PATH? This is my $PATH:

> /home/steve/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin:/home/steve/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

I've searched my ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile, /etc/profile, and /etc/bash.bashrc files, and there is no reference to /home/steve/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin.

How do I replace the $PATH value that was set by my Canopy installation with the default Python installation from my machine? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The installer modifies your .profile or .bash_profile files to include a `source ~/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate` statement, which probably then modifies your path. Look through your dot files for that `source` statement instead of the the enthought path itself.

https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-Canopy

Comment: I found and removed that statement and restarted my shell, but my $PATH remains exactly the same as before.

Comment: Hrm. Did you restart your entire logon session? It's possible it's being inherited from the previous environment. I can't think of any other way that the PATH would persist like this. You could try testing without logging out using `env -i bash`, which should start bash from a completely empty environment.

Comment: Forgive the question, but are you sure that you saved the file after removing that line?

Comment: Thanks antiduh - I hadn't restarted my whole session. Logout + login cleared the Enthough entry from my path.

Comment: Yes, `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.profile` are only read by login shells.  And such confusions/problems were expected, and the next release of Canopy will now edit your `~/.bashrc` file.